# Plugin does not not load code when not used (which is good) > Elementor

Tags: plugins

I am using Elementor which is a page design-builder for WordPress.

It seems that the plugin is not universally loaded throughout the theme when it is not used - is that correct? If so that is great news.

I just want to be 100% sure.

If I view source I see no reference to the plugin hence why I am sure that it doesn't load.

I thought that WordPress plugins, owing to their nature, load on every single page.

Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that WordPress plugins, owing to their nature, load on every
>   single page.

Well it totally depends on what the plugin does. Their are plugins that only do something in the backend, then you will never see any output in the frontend.

Most likely Elementor does a check if any of its functions are being used on the page, before it loads the neccessary scripts and styles.

If you want to be 100% sure, i suggest you ask the developers.